# React Draft Wysiwyg: Empty validator check

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a validator that will check to see if the value is `"<p></p>↵"`... and if it is, display the required message. However, I can't seem to target the ↵ no matter what I try. I've tried to use `trim()` as well, but haven't had any luck.

```
export const isRichTextImageEditorRequired = (value) => value &&
    (!/(\r\n|\n|\r)/.test(value) || isEmpty(value)) ?
    'This field is required' : undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()).blocks.length === 1 & convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()).blocks[0].text === '') {
```

console.log("field required");
}

this is case empty `<p></p>`

Answer (score 0):

trim() works for me, refer the code below . Kindly console you "value" and check if it has any property. In my case it is 'editorText'

code :  values.editorText.trim() === "`<p></p>`"

Comment: It would not work when you change align and not enter text, for example value would be `<p style="text-align:center;"></p>`. Check `blocks` seems to be more accurate.